# addListener behind the scenes

Tags: javascript

In the past I've also used a resize listener that bundled `requestAnimationFrame` with it to be a somewhat optimized version of polling resize events:

```
/**
 * Resize listener
 * @return {function}
 */
export const optimizedResize = (function () {
  let callbacks = [],
    running = false;

  // fired on resize event
  function resize() {
    if (!running) {
      running = true;

      if (window.requestAnimationFrame) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(runCallbacks);
      } else {
        setTimeout(runCallbacks, 66);
      }
    }
  }

  // run the actual callbacks
  function runCallbacks() {
    callbacks.forEach((callback) => {
      callback();
    });

    running = false;
  }

  // adds callback to loop
  function addCallback(callback) {
    if (callback) {
      callbacks.push(callback);
    }
  }

  return {
    // public method to add additional callback
    add(callback) {
      if (!callbacks.length) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
      }
      addCallback(callback);
    },
  };
}());
```

I recently came across [`addListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) which embarrassingly I must say I'm not familiar with. Although it says it's just an alias for `addEventListener()` the syntax seems pretty straight forward to listen to changes:

```
const viewportMediumMin = window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 768px)`);

viewportMediumMin.addListener(checkScreenSize);
```

But, what I'm trying to figure out is `addListener()` is the equivalent of:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    console.log('addEventListener - resize');
}, true);
```

or if it's doing something "smarter" behind the scenes that I should rely on it exclusively, compared to the `optimizedResize` method I mentioned. I'm really only interested in the specific event of the media query changing, not finding out every single pixel width change. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically reinventing wheels. CSS3 was made to style the pages content gracefully on different screen sizes, and media queries were added to change the look of a page at a certain breakpoint. Those breakpoints are common in todays web development, and modern CSS engines were heavily optimized to perform changes as fast as possible. Therefore

```
 window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 768px)`).addListener(/*...*/)
```

is probably very performant as the event is detected by the CSS engine that then gets redirected to the JS engine. Adding a listener to `resize` is probably slower as every pixel change causes a JS event, and your unoptimized JavaScript has to figure out wether a breakpoint was passed. Your `optimizeResize` doesn't really change that.

Comment: Great! Yeah I think so many tutorials of the past have assumed a full-on resize listener was the way to go, but very rarely (if ever) have I needed to listen to every single pixel change; more or less just the moment my condition changes. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @zach well `.matchMedia` is quite new